# What is the mean prime power?

Tags: finite-groups, prime-numbers

I found this definition in a book and I did not understand the meaning of it
**There exists a field of order q if and only if q is a prime power (i.e., $q = p^r$])
with p prime and r ∈ N. Moreover, if q is a prime power, then there is, up to relabelling,
only one field of that order.**

what mean r here, what is value for this variable.
I know Any prime number only divisible by itself and one.
How it take power.

Comment: "prime power" means "power of a prime". $r$ is a positive integer.

Comment: So, for example, $81$ is a prime power because $81=3^4$, while $82$ is not a prime power because it has more than one prime divisor: $82 = 2\cdot41$.

Comment: ... i.e. $q=p^r$ with $p$ prime and $r$ a positive integer

Answer (score 3):

I will focus on the meaning of "prime power":

To say that $q$ is a *prime power* simply means that there exists a positive integer $r$ and a prime number $p$ such that $q=p^r$.  It is not claiming that $q$ is a prime, only that it is only divisible by a single prime.

For example, every prime number $p$ is a prime power by taking $r=1$, as $p=p^1$.  $2,4,8,16,32$ are all prime powers, because they are equal to $2^1,2^2,2^3,2^4,2^5$, respectively.

Non-examples include $6$ because there is no prime $p$ and positive integer $r$ such that $6=p^r$ (this follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic).

Comment: Thank you. ok can you give me some examples please.

Comment: Yep, see the edited answer

Comment: ok Well, I have wondered. Is the number 13 is the prime power. If yes mean that $q=13^1$ then we can say q is make field. from 0 to 12. Is that right.

Comment: @mahmoud_zaiin: Yes any prime is itself also a prime power. Some people also consider $1$ to be a prime power but that is not the usual convention based on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Given a prime $p,$ the set often written $0,1,\ldots, p-1$ is a field under ordinary addition and multiplication modulo $p$ is a field. Call it $F.$ Given a polynomial $f(x)$ with integer coefficients and degree $r,$ such that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $F,$ (and the degree $r$ coefficient is not divisible by $p$) the thing we write as $F[x]/f(x),$ makes another field, this time with $p^r$ elements. The standard basis of this over $F,$ as a vector space, is 
$$ \{x^{r-1}, x^{r-2}, \ldots, x^2, x,1.  \}   $$

Oh, well, there is more to it. An element in this field can be taken to be a polynomial of degree at most $r-1,$ with coefficients in $0,1,\ldots, p-1.$ Addition is still just modulo $p,$ but multiplication needs to include the reduction given by subtracting off polynomial multiples of $f(x),$ which are considered to be zero in this setting.